# Строки при которых код выполняться не будет

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, callback

Ребята. Существует ли способ сделать "Список запрещённых СЛОВ" при которых код в `if` выполнятся не будет? Нужно чтобы `$sendans = 'Девушку';` было не одно слово а несколько. Например Если пользователь напишет слово Девушку или другое запрещённое слово, то код не выполниться. Вопрос: как? Пробовал в массив `array()`, нечего не вышло...

```
<?php 

    if (!isset($_REQUEST)) { 
      return; 
    };
    //UPD: https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=3697615&scope=messages,video,offline,notify,friends,photos,audio,docs,notes,pages,status,wall,groups,notifications
    //Ключ доступа сообщества 
    $token = '***';
    //Ключ доступа пользователя
    $ustoken = '***';

    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

    $sendans = 'Девушку';

    if ($data->type == 'message_new' && $data->object->body != $sendans) {

        $user_id = $data->object->user_id;
      //С помощью messages.send и токена сообщества отправляем ответное сообщение 
        $request_paramser = array( 
          'message' => "Это ответ на IF", 
          'user_id' => $user_id, 
          'access_token' => $token, 
          'v' => '5.64' 
        ); 

    $get_paramser = http_build_query($request_paramser); 

    file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?'. $get_paramser);

    reset($data);
    echo('ok');
    }

?>
```

Comment: Любой анти-мат так работает...

Comment: [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php) не?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
in_array Это действительно то что нужно.
```

Comment: добавьте пример использования